# Mysql_field_names in mysqli using a loop

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, php-7

I have to adapt PHP5 script to PHP7. I almost figured it out everything but I'm blocked on a small part in a query function.
My former colleague used the mysql_field_name function which is no longer available in PHP7.

I've tried to modify the code but it seems that it's not working.

This is the original code:

```
$rep = mysql_query($query);
if ($rep)
{
    $i = 0;
    while($res = mysql_fetch_row($rep))
    {
        for($j=0; $j<count($res); $j++)
        $tabRes[$i][strtoupper(mysql_field_name($rep, $j))] = $res[$j];
        $i++;

    }
}
```

I've tried to replace mysql_field_name by mysqli_fetch_fields .

```
$rep = mysqli_query($this->conn_id,$query);;
if ($rep)
{
    $i = 0;
    while($res = mysqli_fetch_row($rep))
    {
       for($j=0; $j<count($res); $j++)
       $tabRes[$i][strtoupper(mysqli_fetch_fields($rep)->$j)] = $res[$j];              
       $i++;

    }
}
```

How I can fix this issue?

Comment: Note: The object-oriented interface to `mysqli` is significantly less verbose, making code easier to read and audit, and is not easily confused with the obsolete `mysql_query` interface. Before you get too invested in the procedural style it’s worth switching over. Example: `$db = new mysqli(…)` and `$db->prepare("…")` The procedural interface is an artifact from the PHP 4 era when `mysqli` API was introduced and should not be used in new code.

Comment: You may want to switch to `fetch_assoc` which gives you an associative array, something a lot easier to use than having to fetch fields manually on an individual basis.

Comment: Ok thank you, I will keep this in mind and try to adapt it to my code.

Comment: How should I use it  in the loop ?

Comment: Use it instead of `fetch_row`. Have a look at what it contains with `var_dump`.

Answer (score 2):

Check [mysqli_fetch_field_direct](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-field-direct.php), which is among the alternatives after PHP7